# makefile, how do I make reference to the content of a variable?

Tags: debugging, syntax, makefile, gnu

For example, I have a variable $(modules), and this variable contains a list (string separated by spaces) of objects, like *"Modules = obj1 obj2..."* so on.

Each of the obj in the modules also contains a list, let's say *"obj1 = obj1a obj1b..."* so on.

Now, I want to make a variable to contain all these lowest level variables (e.g. obj1a), for example, *"$(variable) = obj1a obj1b...obj2a obj2b..."*

I tried $($(modules))... it obviously didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`foreach` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Foreach-Function):

```
MODULES := foo bar baz

foo := a b c
bar := i j k
baz := x y z

FLAT_MODULES := $(foreach m,$(MODULES),$($m))
# FLAT_MODULES is now 'a b c i j k x y z'
```

Answer (score 0):

So, from what you described, let's suppose you have three variables, obj1, obj2, and obj3 that hold your "object" names. Then, you want a variable, say MODULES, to hold the contents of these three variables.

Wouldn't something like the code below do what you want?

```
.PHONY: test

MODULES=$(obj1) $(obj2) $(obj3)
obj1=foo1 bar1
obj2=foo2 bar2
obj3=foo3 bar3

all:
    echo $(MODULES)
```

Obviously substituting the "echo" to whatever you want?

Comment: I figured it out, and you can avoid that $(obj1) $(obj2) $(obj3)
with a foreach function as described by the previous guy. Thank you very much too.